# Why does it failed to open the stream

Tags: php, html

My explanation is not perfect but i tried my best.

This is my root path code...

```
<?php

define("ROOT_PATH", realpath(dirname("_FILE_")));
define("BASE_URL", "http://localhost:82/blog");
```

so I tried calling adminHeader.php into my create.php. This is the Create.php code ...

```
<?php include("../../path.php"); ?>      <!-- to get access to the path.php, i first stepped out of 
topics folder the ../ then the admin folder ../ then into the blog folder to access the path.php. -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="EN">

 <head>
 </head>
 <body>

 <?php include(ROOT_PATH . "\app\includes\adminHeader.php"); ?>
 
 </body>
 </html>
```

and this the error i'm getting when run it in the browser using Chrome. Please help me out. Thank you.

Warning: include(C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\admin\topics\app\includes\adminHeader.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\admin\topics\create.php on line 26

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\admin\topics\app\includes\adminHeader.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\admin\topics\create.php on line 26

Comment: Looks like this file doesn't exists `C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\admin\topics\app\includes\adminHeader.php`

Comment: Yh that's true, this is suppose to be the right path. C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\app\includes\adminHeader.php. but it directing to otherwise. please can you help me to direct it correctly?. Thanks